When should @Environment var be private in SwiftUI?
@Environment(MyEnvironmentObj.self) var myVar
vs
@Environment(MyEnvironmentObj.self) private var myVar
I've seen that Apple uses the former in their recent tutorials, but I use private in my code, which seems to work great, and I thought private was encouraged whenever possible?

The "recent tutorials" link links to stackoverflow.com. Did you mean to put a different link?

Some SwiftUI property wrappers (e.g. @State) are recommended to be declared private because users of your view might accidentally pass values for them into the automatically generated memberwise initialiser.
From the documentation of @State,

Declare state as private to prevent setting it in a memberwise initializer, which can conflict with the storage management that SwiftUI provides.

Here is a simple example to demonstrate this. Suppose you wrote a view like this:
struct NonPrivateState: View {
    @State var foo = 0
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(foo)")
    }
}

and several months later you forgot that foo is a @State, and might think that you need to pass something to the foo: parameter. As a result you did this:
@State var x = 0

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        NonPrivateState(foo: x)
        Button("Change x") {
            x += 1
        }
    }
}

You'd find that the button doesn't work at all.
This is less of an issue with @Environment, because for @Environment, the automatically generated memberwise initialiser would take an Environment as the parameter, and so you are more likely to realise that you are not supposed to pass this parameter.
struct Foo: View {
    @Environment(\.isEnabled) var enabled

    // this generates a memberwise initialiser like this:
    init(enabled: Environment<Bool> = Environment(\.isEnabled)) {
        _enabled = enabled
    }

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}

Even if you try to pass a parameter to enabled, you cannot pass a Bool directly. That said, it is possible in this case to pass Environment(\.isScrollEnabled) (which also happens to be Environment<Bool>), and consequently would cause the view to read the wrong environment value. It is also possible to pass an @Environment property from the parent view too, which causes any changes to the subview's environment to be ignored.
Here is a simple example demonstrating this:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Foo() // this will show true
            Foo(enabled: .init(\.isScrollEnabled)) // this will show false
        }
        .scrollDisabled(true) // sets isScrollEnabled to false
        .environment(\.isEnabled, true)
    }
}

struct Foo: View {
    @Environment(\.isEnabled) var enabled
    var body: some View {
        Text(verbatim: "\(enabled)")
    }
}

The same holds for @Observable environment objects. If the view expects Environment<SomeClass>, one can technically pass it Environment(SomeSubclass.self), causing the view to get the wrong object. But again, this is very unlikely to happen.

Making @Environment private would prevent these things from happening, as well as hide the implementation detail of exactly which environment values your view depends on.
You could also argue that because these things are already very unlikely, it is not worth the effort of writing private everywhere.
